# Using long in place of int causes extra cases of overflow in java. Why?

Tags: java

I wrote a solution for a Hackerrank challenge in which I sum a large amount of numbers into a total variable. When I used ints, I noticed I was overflowing in one test case, but all other test cases were outputting the correct answer. When I switched my `total` variable to a long to avoid overflowing, I started overflowing in *two* test cases (the same one as before and another one). Once I changed `total`, `numToSell`, *and* `lastMax` to longs, the program calculate the correct answer.

What would cause this to happen? I would expect that moving a variable from int to long should never cause overflow.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int T = in.nextInt();
        while(T-->0)
        {
            int N = in.nextInt(); 
            int[] price = new int[N];

            for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            {
                price[i] = in.nextInt();
            }

            int lastMax = price[N-1]; //works when this and numToSell are longs
            int numToSell = 0; 
            long total = 0; //if this is also an int, only overflows in one case in my samples
            for(int i  = N - 2; i >= 0; --i)
            {
                if(price[i] <= lastMax)
                {
                    ++numToSell;
                    total -= price[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    total += numToSell*lastMax;
                    lastMax = price[i];
                    numToSell = 0;
                }
            }
            total += numToSell*lastMax;
            System.out.println(total);

        }
    }
}
```

In the affected test case N is 39,384 and each number in the array is between 1 and 100000.

Comment: Can you provide the smallest amount of input data that causes the problem?

Comment: I think you will be able to answer your own question using a debugger and maybe some spot checks on the sign of your variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If total, numToSell, and lastMax, are all ints, there are some cases where things can cancel and give you the correct answer, accidentally.  This doesn't necessarily happen if total is long but the other are ints.

Here's an example that walks through the loop.

```
prices = {2000001,2000000,2000000,2000000};
lastMax = 2000000;
numToSell = 0;
total = 0;
loop:
  iteration 1:
    numToSell = 1;
    total = -2000000  
  iteration 2:
    numToSell = 2;
    total = -4000000  // oh no, we underflowed if we are int, but not long!
  iteration 3:
    total = -4000000 + (2 * 2000000)  // let's take a deeper look at this below
    numToSell = 0;
    lastMax = 20000001
total += 0;
```

Let's take a look at this line: total = -4000000 + (2 * 2000000)

If total, numToSell, and lastMax are all ints, then total = 0.  This is because total underflowed and (2 * 20000000) will overflow in the exact same way.  So the two cancel out.

If they are all longs, then nothing overflows so total = -40000000 + (2 * 2000000) = 0.

If total is long, then total did not underflow when it was set to -4000000.  But, (2 * 2000000) is an integer, which will overflow and become a negative number.  So total will not be zero!

This is a case when having all ints works, having all longs works, but having a mix fails.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I knew int*int would do an 32 bit multiply, but I thought numToSell*lastMax were too small to overflow an int, but they could actually be 50k*100k = 5 billion. In my particular sample case the last totalling operation was -1897992076 + -426605980 = 1970369240 which was somehow magically right. The judge seemed to have this happen on multiple hidden test cases other than this particular one.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because here

```
total += numToSell*lastMax;
```

if `numToSell` and `lastMax` are `int` that's integer multiplication. int * int = int. You then added the `int` to your `long`. When `numToSell` (or `lastMax`) is a long that particular multiplication instruction will work as you expect. And I note you perform that math in two places.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing if you just changed `total` to long and left `numToSell` and `lastMax` as int, then `numToSell*lastMax` would still overflow and giving you incorrect result which is then added onto `total`